# How to integrate Angularjs into elasticpath

Tags: customization, elasticpath

I am working on commerce platform with WCS. I am going through the Elasticpath material. Is there any way to integrate angularjs as the frontend with Elasticpath?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a log in for the docs site (should come with your company's license), then you can look through their [docs](https://developers.elasticpath.com/) to figure out the endpoint for studio.

[Here is a demo on their site hooked up to demo data.](https://touchpoint-developers.elasticpath.com/studio) (try searching for nemo)

You can use studio to interact with elasticpath's API. Just connect to these with any version of Angular's HTTP service like you would any other API.